# AD Properties: What is the difference between Modified and modifyTimeStamp

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have found: the `modifyTimeStamp` is contructed from `whenChanged`, both of which are not replicated.

However, I have not been able to find a definition or explanation for the `Modified` property, though `Modified` reflects the same stamp as `modifyTimeStamp` and `whenChanged`.

So, what is the difference between `Modified` and `modifyTimeStamp`, and which value is best to use if I need to do some work on an object--delete, move, disable, etc.

eg:

`if ($modifytimestamp -le $somepointintime) { do something because nothing has been done since somepointintime }`

Or, what is the best property to use if I need to do something to an object based upon time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Modified` is not actually a real attribute. It's another one of those "value-added" attributes like you mention (not to be confused with actual AD "constructed" attributes) that is inserted at runtime by the Powershell Cmdlet. Just to make the output more user friendly. And also confuse people. ;)  That's why you can't find a definition for it from MSDN's docs.

You're right - neither `modifyTimeStamp` or `whenChanged` are replicated by default.

Your options are 1) mark the attribute as replicated, or 2) query all your domain controllers and pick the most recent time.

Read this blog post if you haven't already:

- 2006-10-03, Joe Richards, *"whenChanged and modifyTimeStamp"*, https://blog.joeware.net/2006/10/03/655/ (Archived [here](https://archive.is/wip/JG8aA).)